# TIJ-4 метод finalize()

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора

Начал свое обучение Java с книжки Б.Еккеля Философия Ява. Добрался до метода finalize(). В книге приведен пример:

```
//: initialization/TerminationCondition.java
// Using finalize() to detect an object that
// hasn't been properly cleaned up.

class Book {
  boolean checkedOut = false;
  Book(boolean checkOut) {
    checkedOut = checkOut;
  }
  void checkIn() {
    checkedOut = false;
  }
  protected void finalize() {
    if(checkedOut)
      System.out.println("Error: checked out");
    // Normally, you'll also do this:
    // super.finalize(); // Call the base-class version
  }
}

public class TerminationCondition {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Book novel = new Book(true);
    // Proper cleanup:
    novel.checkIn();
    // Drop the reference, forget to clean up:
new Book(true);

    // Force garbage collection & finalization:
    System.gc();
  }
} /* Output:
Error: checked out
*///:~
```

И вроде бы все понятно, но вот никак не могу уразуметь, почему в методе finalize() условие if выполняется если checkedOut==true. Ведь по умолчанию boolean являются false.

Я еще лошара в коддинге, поэтому если не правильно задаю вопрос, не могли бы вы подробно описать что конкретно делает метод finalize() в данном примере.

Спасибо!

Comment: Условие выполняется для одного экземпляра или обоих? Так то у анонимного объекта (`new Book(true);`) значение `checkedOut` в конструкторе в `true` выставлено.

Answer (score 1):

Да, по умолчанию `checkedOut` является **false**, но есть конструктор, который принимает значение `checkedOut`. Но в `Book novel = new Book(true);` и в `new Book(true);` параметр - **true**.
 Отсюда и вытекает, что в методе `finalize` продолжает свою работу.
Строчка `if(checkOut)` подразумевает `if(checkOut == true)`

Comment: Я понимаю что ссылки Book novel = new Book(true); и в new Book(true); параметр - true; После исполнения кода выводится "Error: checked out". Но если им присвоить параметр false, никакого сообщения не выводится. И я не могу понять почему.

Comment: сообщение не выводиться, так как условие это не позволяет. Посмотрите при каком условии фраза должна выводиться

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый респонс. Вот как я вижу это условие метода finalize(): if(checkedOut==false) sout("Error: checked out"). Новая ссылка new Book(true) передает параметр true, значит условие не выполняется и строка не должна выводиться. А на практике все да наоборот

Comment: Я знаю что я не прав, пожалуйста подскажите где конкретно

Comment: Если можете, примите ответ, буду благодарен) @Ruslan

Comment: изменил ответ до конца

Comment: Вы написали: Строчка if(checkOut) подразумевает if(checkOut == true). Но почему true? Вот он главный вопрос, что я задал изначально

Comment: @Ruslan вы написали, что видите if(checkedOut==false) sout("Error: checked out"), но все происходит наоборот. Вывод идет, только если checkOut == true

Comment: Да я понял что вывод идет если checkOut==true. Но не могу понять почему. Я уже этот код наизусть выучил, перепробовал 500 изменений, что бы понять логику. Ведь в условии if нет явного присвоения checkOut==true, там просто if(checkOut), то есть boolean по умолчанию, значит false. Знаю я тупой и не могу понять простейших вещей, но вы мне не помогли, а просто сыграли роль консоли. Ваш ответ констатирует факты, но не дает объяснения.

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал заменить boolean на int и вот что получилось. Здесь все понятно и поддается логике. Допустим false это 1, а true любой другой int:

```
class FinTest {
    int a = 1; // false
    FinTest (int a1) {
        a=a1;
    }
    void finish() {
        a=1; // false
    }
    protected void finalize () {
        if(a!=1) // if (true)
            System.out.println(a+" - Error");
    }
}

public class Finalize {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FinTest x = new FinTest(2); // true
        x.finish();
        new FinTest(0); // true

        System.gc();
    }
}
```

Никаких вопросов в данном примере нет. Но объясните мне пожалуйста, в какой момент в оригинальном примере checkedOut принимает значение true и условие if(checkedOut) равносильно if(true)?

Comment: а где у вас переменная `a` принимает значение отличное от `1`?

Comment: после создания объекта класса FinTest, далее сравнивается с условием в методе finalize(), "если !=1 то пиши строку", в случае уборки, и это логично.  Но в оригинальном примере я вижу условие "если false то пиши строку", так как не было явного указания if(checkedOut==true), там стоит просто if(checkedOut), то есть boolean со значением по умолчанию, а значит с false. И так как "потерянный" объект new Book(true), то по идее он не должен подходить под условие метода finalize(), а следовательно не должен выводить строку.

Comment: "if(checkedOut), то есть boolean со значением по умолчанию, а значит с false" - это неверно. В скобках у `if` находится логическое выражение, которое может состоять из одного операнда логического типа, в этом случае значением выражения является значение операнда. Вообще, писать `if(checkedOut == true)` (а так же `while(bool != true)`, `return bool == true ? true : false` и т.п.) излишне.

Comment: @zRrr, спасибо, вроде бы подбираюсь к истине. То есть значение операнда в этом случае принимает значение ссылки new Book(true)? И если бы она была new Book(false), тогда и операнд условия if принял бы значение false?

Comment: поведение `if` определяется значением поля `checkedOut` (можете написать перед `if` `System.out.println(checkedOut);`), которое задается в конструкторе значением параметра `checkOut`, которое при вызове `new Book(true)` равно `true`. Да, если бы был `new Book(false)`, то был бы `false` и сообщение не вывелось бы.

Comment: @zRrr вроде бы наконец дошло. Спасибо за разжевывание! Если скопируете этот коммент как ответ, я поставлю его принятым.